# immersions losing focus in google glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

When you are using glassware based on live cards, such as the timer or compass samples, the live card will be the first thing you see as soon as you wake up glass after having the screen turn off. In other words, you will see the live card as soon as you turn on the screen if it had focus when the screen turned off.

Is there any way to replicate this behavior in an immersion? I don't want users to leave the immersion unless they explicitly swipe down. I also do not want to use a wakelock to keep the screen on ala spellista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed working as intended: if you would like the screen to timeout while keeping the user in your immersion, you should take care of doing this programmatically.

Additionally, you could also use both an immersion and a LiveCard, the LiveCard being a window to your immersion that is triggered by a user tap.

Comment: Could you explain "take care of doing this programmatically"? How can I keep the user in my immersion after the screen timed out, and the user taps or looks up to wake it up?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to actually set the `android:immersive="true"` attribute for the `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. A more advanced way to do so would be to acquire the wakelock and take care of dimming the screen according to internal states of your Glassware.